# Volley custom Post request with GSON

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I am new to volley and I just want to ask on how to `POST` request with `GSON`.

Following the tutorial here: [Volley custom request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom)

This is my object class.

```
class Account {
    @SerializedName("status")
    var status: String? = null

    @SerializedName("token")
    var token: String? = null

    @SerializedName("user")
    var user:  AccountInfo? = null
}

class AccountInfo(val id: Int, val username: String, val password: String)
```

This is my request function.

```
private fun doRequest() {
    val url = "http://www.xxxwebportalxxx.com/api/user/login/"
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

    val jsonObject = JSONObject()
    jsonObject.put("username", "user@gmail.com")
    jsonObject.put("password", "123456xxx")

    val hashMap = HashMap<String, String>()
    hashMap["public-key"] = "0123456789qwertyuiop"
    hashMap["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    val gsonRequest = GsonRequest(url, Account::class.java, hashMap, jsonObject,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                Log.i("response", "$response")
            },
            Response.ErrorListener {

            }
    )
    queue.add(gsonRequest)
}
```

and this is the code provided from the tutorial but instead of using `GET` I changed it to `POST` and add some `JSONObject` inside to provide a `BODY`.

```
class GsonRequest<T>(
        url: String,
        private val clazz: Class<T>,
        private val headers: MutableMap<String, String>?,
        private val data: JSONObject,
        private val listener: Response.Listener<T>,
        errorListener: Response.ErrorListener
) : Request<T>(Method.POST, url, errorListener) {
    private val gson = Gson()

    override fun getBody(): ByteArray {
        return gson.toJson(data).toByteArray()
    }

    override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> = headers ?: super.getHeaders()

    override fun deliverResponse(response: T) = listener.onResponse(response)

    override fun parseNetworkResponse(response: NetworkResponse?): Response<T> {
        return try {
            val json = String(
                    response?.data ?: ByteArray(0),
                    Charset.forName(HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response?.headers)))
            Response.success(
                    gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response))
        } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
            Response.error(ParseError(e))
        } catch (e: JsonSyntaxException) {
            Response.error(ParseError(e))
        }
    }
}
```

and this is what I got when performing the `doRequest()`.

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/Volley: [320] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://www.xxxwebportalxxx.com/api/user/login/ 0xc0da6ea6 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=6043], [size=16], [rc=401], [retryCount=1]
E/Volley: [298] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for http://www.xxxwebportalxxx.com/api/user/login/
```

and lastly this is my expected output.

```
{ 
  "status" : true,
  "token" : "fake-token-generated",
  "user":  {
    "id": "1",
    "username": "user@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456xxx"
  }
}
```

Did I miss something or my code is really wrong when requesting a `POST`? Help me guys Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the right Content-Type? Since your body is a JSON, I'd put `application/json`. Maybe that's what your issue is all about

Comment: yes, the Content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` should I change something?

Comment: If you're implementing any type of web client - setup debug proxy. You will see exactly what comes out the device and what is returned in the response. Then it's easy to compare it to documentation. I'm using Charles proxy, but you can use mitm or even stetho.

Comment: @dotGitignore it depends on what the webservice expects. Maybe it accepts both content types, but if you put a JSON with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the server might not be able to correctly parse the JSON